# MapFragment - Google Maps Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, out-of-memory

I've been getting these crashes for a while now , I've looked around and tried one suggested solution which is to use the `googleMap.clear()` which didn't work as I'm still getting the crash reported , I'm using the latest `google play service library 8.1.0` and  `compileSdkVersion 23`  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1".
also this crash seems to be only occurring  on android 5.0

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 1301325 free bytes and 1270KB until OOM 1
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) 2
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) 3
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:939) 4
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:912) 5
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879) 6
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.i.a(Unknown Source) 7
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.a(Unknown Source) 8
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.a(Unknown Source) 9
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.b(Unknown Source) 10
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.b.ak.a(Unknown Source) 11
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.b.as.a(Unknown Source) 12
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.x.a(Unknown Source) 13
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.l.a(Unknown Source) 14
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.l.b(Unknown Source) 15
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.cv.f(Unknown Source) 16
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.cv.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you adding a load of annotations and overlays? Can you let us know what you're doing to your map

Comment: try system.gc() and map.clear() before initializing map.

Comment: @Amrut i did call map.clear before initializing, no joy.

Comment: @DiscoS2 im only adding markers to the map, just places geo locations

Comment: How many though? And what are you using for the marker images?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in application tag of your Manifest file

Comment: from [google docs] (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)
"Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix". Im looking for another cleaner approach to this than just using more memoery, my app doesnt use much memory, as i montierd the memory usage and didnt see a high memory usage .@Nitesh

Comment: @Amrut invoking System.gc() only requests the JVM to run the garbage collector, it doesn't necessarily gets executed, and even if it would have, only the objects with no live references would be garbage collected.

While running memory intensive applications in devices with low RAM, it is good to mention the above written tag.(Consdering we have written as much optimized code as humanly possible)